# htaccess redirection for query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I want to redirect my dynamic URLs to static for SEO purpose with .htaccess.
The URLs are as mentioned below:

1. http://www.manpowersupplyfromnepal.com/index.php?page=home
2. /index.php?page=about-us

and so on

I want to make them as mentioned below respectively.

1. http://www.manpowersupplyfromnepal.com/
2. /about-us

Please reply to me with appropriate solution. I will be grateful.

Thank you,

Nitin

Answer (score 0):

please see the code below it will help you out Please try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=home$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.manpowersupplyfromnepal.com/home? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=about-us$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.manpowersupplyfromnepal.com/about-us? [R=301,L]
```

Alternative

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=about-us$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://www.manpowersupplyfromnepal.com/about-us? [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect the URL permanently as well as you will get your desired URL without query string